# Tkinter progress bar/window not responding when moved

Tags: python, progress-bar, tkinter, move

I have borrowed a progress bar from [here](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/ProgressMeter) that I would like to adapt work in my program with global variables.  Here is the code for reference:

```
import Tkinter

class Meter(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, width=300, height=20, bg='white', fillcolor='orchid1',\
                 value=0.0, text=None, font=None, textcolor='black', *args, **kw):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master, bg=bg, width=width, height=height, *args, **kw)
        self._value = value

        self._canv = Tkinter.Canvas(self, bg=self['bg'], width=self['width'], height=self['height'],\
                                    highlightthickness=0, relief='flat', bd=0)
        self._canv.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self._rect = self._canv.create_rectangle(0, 0, 0, self._canv.winfo_reqheight(), fill=fillcolor,\
                                                 width=0)
        self._text = self._canv.create_text(self._canv.winfo_reqwidth()/2, self._canv.winfo_reqheight()/2,\
                                            text='', fill=textcolor)
        if font:
            self._canv.itemconfigure(self._text, font=font)

        self.set(value, text)
        self.bind('<Configure>', self._update_coords)

    def _update_coords(self, event):
        '''Updates the position of the text and rectangle inside the canvas when the size of
        the widget gets changed.'''
        # looks like we have to call update_idletasks() twice to make sure
        # to get the results we expect
        self._canv.update_idletasks()
        self._canv.coords(self._text, self._canv.winfo_width()/2, self._canv.winfo_height()/2)
        self._canv.coords(self._rect, 0, 0, self._canv.winfo_width()*self._value, self._canv.winfo_height())
        self._canv.update_idletasks()

    def get(self):
        return self._value, self._canv.itemcget(self._text, 'text')

    def set(self, value=0.0, text=None):
        #make the value failsafe:
        if value < 0.0:
            value = 0.0
        elif value > 1.0:
            value = 1.0
        self._value = value
        if text == None:
            #if no text is specified use the default percentage string:
            text = str(int(round(100 * value))) + ' %'
        self._canv.coords(self._rect, 0, 0, self._canv.winfo_width()*value, self._canv.winfo_height())
        self._canv.itemconfigure(self._text, text=text)
        self._canv.update_idletasks()

##-------------demo code--------------------------------------------##

def _demo(meter, value):
    meter.set(value)
    if value < 1.0:
        value = value + 0.005
        meter.after(50, lambda: _demo(meter, value))
    else:
        meter.set(value, 'Demo successfully finished')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk(className='meter demo')
    m = Meter(root, relief='ridge', bd=3)
    m.pack(fill='x')
    m.set(0.0, 'Starting demo...')
    m.after(1000, lambda: _demo(m, 0.0))
    root.mainloop()
```

This code and demo work great, but when I make the following changes so I can test how I would want to impliment it into my code, the progress window becomes unresponsive and turns blank whenever I move it or activate another window.

```
##-------------demo code--------------------------------------------##

def some_fct(m):
    global count
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        count = count + 1
        sleep(2)
        m.set(float(count) / total)
        i = i + 1

def other_fct(m):
    global count
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        count = count + 1
        sleep(2)
        m.set(float(count) / total)
        i = i + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global count
    global total
    count = 0
    total = 10
    root = Tkinter.Tk(className='meter demo')
    m = Meter(root, relief='ridge', bd=3)
    m.pack(fill='x')
    m.set(0.0, 'Starting meter')
    some_fct(m)
    other_fct(m)
    root.mainloop()
```

Any idea what is going on here and why it becomes unresponsive?  Does it have anything to do with the global variable being used?  It seems to work "ok" when it's not moved, but it's definitely not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I used to get what I wanted:

```
##-------------demo code--------------------------------------------##

def count_numbers(number):
    i = 0
    while i < number:
        i = i + 1

def some_fct():
    global count
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        count = count + 1
        count_numbers(5000000)
        i = i + 1

def other_fct():
    global count
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        count = count + 1
        count_numbers(5000000)
        i = i + 1

def do_stuff():
    some_fct()
    other_fct()

def update_progress(m):
    value = float(count) / total
    if value < 1.0:
        m.set(value)
        m.after(500, lambda: update_progress(m))
    else:
        m.set(value, 'Process Completed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global count
    global total
    count = 0
    total = 10
    root = Tkinter.Tk(className='meter demo')
    m = Meter(root, relief='ridge', bd=3)
    m.pack(fill='x')
    m.set(0.0, 'Starting meter')    
    m.after(50, lambda: update_progress(m))
    thread.start_new_thread(do_stuff, () )
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

`some_fct` and `other_fct` both sleep for 10 seconds each, so the app will be unresponsive for at least 20 seconds when it starts up since those sleeps all happen before `mainloop` is called. Are you saying that even after those 20 seconds the app is unresponsive, or are you asking why it's unresponsive for the first 20 seconds?

Tkinter is single threaded, which means that any time you put in a sleep it's not going to be able to service events for the duration of the sleep. It is this servicing of events that defines "responsiveness".

Comment: The unresponsiveness is from the meter window. When the program is run you see the meter progress 10%, 20%, 30%... etc. But as soon as you click on the progress window and try to move it, or click on a different window (both of these while program is running and counting) the progress bar window becomes blank and un responsive. Sometimes it gets the "Not Responding" next to the title in Windows XP. I have the sleeps in there so you can see it do something.

Comment: It is "unresponsive" because it is the `mainloop` that "responds". So, until `mainloop` runs it will pretty much by definition be unresponsive.  The reason you see anything at all is that your code occasionally calls `update_idletasks` which forces the screen to update. Any event processing (which is how a window responds to mouse clicks, movement, gaining focus, etc) won't happen until the event loop is entered.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, in order to see the progress bar correctly the program should be in `mainloop`? If so, is it even possible for a program to be in `mainloop` as well as completing other tasks (such as `some_fct` and `other fct`). I don't really see how the original demo code got away with this. Was `root.mainloop()` run immidiately after the `m.after()` command and before it went into the recursive `_demo` code?

Comment: Yes, in order to see the progress bar correctly `mainloop` should be running. The original demo code works because it puts something in the event queue (using `after`) then immediately starts the event loop. The event loop sees something on the queue, pulls it off, and runs that code. In the process of running that code a new job (the "recursive" call) is added to the event queue. Lather, rinse, repeat. It's not actually recursive, it's simply requesting that the even loop call it again after a certain period of time.

Comment: After modifying the `some_fct()` and `other_fct()` calls in the main program to a `m.after(1000, lambda: do_stuff(m))` where `do_stuff` calls `some_fct()` and `other_fct()` I still have the same problem.  Shouldn't this have fixed this?

Comment: no. If you call `sleep`, your app will sleep. It doesn't matter where you call it from. Tkinter is single threaded; while you're busy looping and sleeping the app cannot service events. If it can't service events it will be unresponsive.

Comment: Well I actually replaced the `sleep` with a `while i < 5000000: i = i + 1` and I have the same issue.  Shouldn't it update the window every time the `set` command is used any way?  I just don't really see what the difference between the two programs are, I just know mine doesn't work properly.

Comment: No, it won't update the window every time `set` is used. Why would you think that? Again, Tkinter is single threaded. While your code is in the `while i < 5000000` loop it can't service events (unless you explicitly call `update`, but opens up a whole can of worms)

Comment: The difference between the two programs is, the original adds a request to do a small chunk of work and then returns to the event loop. Each small chuck adds another small chunk before returning to the event loop. In your case you're doing one large chunk of work before returning to the event loop. Once more: Tkinter is single threaded -- while it's doing your big chunk of work or is sleeping it can't process other events such as mouse clicks, repaint requests, etc.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  So basically a progress bar written in Tkinter is impossible because it can't service the window and complete the actual code at the same time?

Comment: @Das Rot: Do NOT call `update`. That will create a *new* event loop. Until you fully understand how the event loop works you shouldn't ever call `update`. The event loop is effectively an infinite loop. When you call `update` you're in effect calling an infinite loop from inside an infinite loop. Do you see the problem?

Comment: No, it's not impossible to write a progress bar. The original code proves that. It's simply impossible to write a progress bar *and* have code that takes a long time to process. Once again, Tkinter is single threaded. If it's running your long calculation it can't service events. You can either run your code in a separate thread, or break up your work into manageable chunks like the original code does.

Comment: So how would I go about running code in a "separate thread"?  I have tried a `m.after(100, lambda: update_progress(m))` with a `m.after(100, lambda: do_stuff(m))` afterwards where `update_progress` is basically `_demo` from the original demo, with the addition of setting the value from global `count` and does an `update` on the window.  It still seems to do one of the process before the other instead.  Any more wisdom?  Is this not a realistic program?  I would just like to have a refresh loop that sets `value` to global value and also performs a main function that calculates (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) the global value among other things.  The refresh loop (refreshes progress bar with `update`) would then finish when the main function is finished.  Is this multi-threading possible in python?

Comment: I guess what I am REALLY looking for is a window service that will re-draw itself without me having to tell it to in Python.  Is this not possible in Python?

Comment: It's impossible to give you a complete tutorial of Tkinter in the comments of a SO question. You seem to want to run things in a loop. The event loop is a loop. So, break up what you want into small chunks and run them via after, just like the original code. OR, put all your code in a separate thread so that it doesn't block the GUI.

Comment: I didn't realize until now that thread is an actual built-in module.  I believe thread.start_new_thread () is what I am looking for.  I will have to wait until tomorrow to test it out.  Thank you for your help.